# How can i get a value inside and an overriden method

Tags: java, methods

```
for (final Type type : category.getTypes()) {
    TableColumn<Item, Integer> col = new TableColumn<Item, Integer>(type.getName());

    col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Item>,
            ObservableValue<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(CellDataFeatures<Item> item) {
            return item.getValue().getPrice(type);
        }
    });
    priceColumn.add(col);
}
```

How do i get the value of type inside call method ??

Comment: What do you want to do and how is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a setType() and save the type as part of the first statement in the for loop. Create a static getType and access the type in the Callback class.

```
// New Modifed code
Class Test
{
Type type = null;
public void setType(type)
{
this.type = type;
}

public static Type getType()
{
return type;
}

for (final Type type : category.getTypes()) {
    setType(type);
    TableColumn<Item, Integer> col = new TableColumn<Item, Integer>(type.getName());

    col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Item>,
            ObservableValue<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(CellDataFeatures<Item> item) {
            return item.getValue().getPrice(Test.getType());
        }
    });
   priceColumn.add(col);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to write another method `void call(CellDataFeatures<Item> item, Type type)`. This way your are able to just call that method inside your for-loop. I dont know if I completly understood your problem.